# Changing place of numbers in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Certainly, a duplicate but I have not found it:

I have two lists

```
u = {2,3,0,0}
v = {4,0,0,6}
```

I want the zeros of the first at the same place that the zeros of the second

I have tried with `Sort` with `Position` but in that case the order matters. I want only the position --- it may be other numbers than zeros.

Comment: What is the expected result? Will the count of zeros be always the same?

Comment: You are clearly around voting and accepting, is there any reason why you are ignoring my questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pattern matching on the internal form of [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html):

```
u = {6, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, -3, -9};
v = {3, -2, 1, 5, 0, 4, 0, 0};

SparseArray /@ {u, v} /.
  {_[__, {__, k_}], a_[i__, {j__, _}]} :> a[i, {j, k}] // Normal
```

> ```
> {6, 1, 2, -3, 0, -9, 0, 0}
> ```

Answer (score 8):

```
sa = SparseArray;
sa[sa[v]["NonzeroPositions"] -> sa[u]["NonzeroValues"], Length[v]] // Normal
```

> {2, 0, 0, 3}

**Update:** Turning the method above into a function and adding two more alternatives

```
ClearAll[f1,f2,f3]
f1 = Module[{pos = SparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"], 
     vals = SparseArray[#2]["NonzeroValues"]}, Normal@SparseArray[pos->vals, Length@#]]&;
f2 = Module[{w = #, pos = Position[#, Except[0], 1, Heads -> False], 
     vals = DeleteCases[#2, 0]}, MapThread[(w[[#]] = #2)&, {pos, vals}]; w]&;
f3 = Module[{i = 1, w = #, pos = Position[#,Except[0],1, Heads -> False], 
     vals = DeleteCases[#2, 0]}, MapAt[vals[[i++]]&, w, pos]]&;
```

Examples:

```
u = {2, 3, 0, 0};
v = {4, 0, 0, 6} ;
f1[v, u]
```

> {2, 0, 0, 3}

```
f1[u, v]
```

> {4, 6, 0, 0}

```
Equal @@ (#[v, u] & /@ {f1, f2, f3})
```

> True

Answer (score 7):

```
u = {2, 3, 0, 0};
v = {4, 0, 0, 6};

Fold[Insert[#1, 0, #2] &, DeleteCases[u, 0], Position[v, 0]]
```

> {2, 0, 0, 3}

Lists can have different lengths

```
u = {1, 2, 3};
v = {0, 0};
```

> {0, 0, 1, 2, 3}

Answer (score 5):

```
Module[{i = 0}
  , Replace[v, Except[0] :> #[[++i]], {1}] & @ DeleteCases[u, 0]
]
```

> {2, 0, 0, 3}

Answer (score 4):

This works only if `Count[u, 0] === Count[v, 0]`

```
sz = 20;
u = RandomInteger[{1, sz}, sz] (zeros = RandomInteger[1, sz])
v = RandomInteger[{1, sz}, sz] RandomSample[zeros]

res = u[[Ordering[Sign[u]][[Ordering[Ordering[Sign[v]]]]]]]
```

If `Count[u, 0] > Count[v, 0]`, I find it most intuitive to match/reposition the *first*  `Count[v, 0]` zeros of `u` while keeping the remaining zeros in place, and when `Count[u, 0] < Count[v, 0]` to match all zeros of `u` with the *first* `Count[u, 0]` zeros of `v`. E.g.
`u = {2,3,0,0}; v = {4,0,1,6}` yields `{2,0,3,0}` and
`u = {2,3,1,0}; v = {4,0,0,6}` yields `{2,0,3,1}` or in code:

```
Evaluate[PadRight[DeleteCases[Insert[u[[Ordering[-Sign[u]]]],
  #, # - Range[0, Length[#] - 1] &[Take[Position[v, 0, {1}],
    UpTo[Count[u, 0]]]]], 0], Length[v], 0]] &[0]
```

For all cases if `u` and `v` contain negative numbers, you need to replace `Sign` by `Abs@*Sign`

Answer (score 1):

Terse in-place form of Coolwater's method:

```
u = {2, 3, 0, 0};
v = {4, 0, 0, 6};

(u[[#]] = u[[#2]]) & @@ Ordering /@ Unitize@{u, v};

u
```

> ```
> {2, 0, 0, 3}
> ```

Works with negatives by default:

```
u = {6, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, -3, -9};
v = {3, -2, 1, 5, 0, 4, 0, 0};

(u[[#]] = u[[#2]]) & @@ Ordering /@ Unitize@{u, v};

u
```

> ```
> {6, 1, 2, -3, 0, -9, 0, 0}
> ```